# Symfony 6 ManyToMAny OneToMany ArrayCollection matching criteria IN('value1', 'value2', ...)

Tags: many-to-many, one-to-many, symfony6, arraycollection

I want to match related child entities field 'status' if it has one of the values  ['not_started', 'in_progress']. I get an error "array to string conversion". Am I using it wrong?

```php
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;


/** @var ArrayCollection $tasks */

$criteria = Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->in('status', ['not_started', 'in_progress']));

/** @var Collection<int, Task> $openTasks */

$openTasks = $tasks->matching($criteria);
```

All other matching expressions are working because they use string instead of array but I need to check for multiple values at once and I don't want to use ArrayCollection->filter.

Edit:

I also tried this:

```php
$statusValues = [Statuses::NOT_STARTED, Statuses::IN_PROGRESS];
/** @var ArrayCollection $tasks */

/** @var Expression[] $statusExpressions */

$statusExpressions = [];

foreach ($statusValues as $statusValue) {
    $statusExpressions[] = Criteria::expr()->eq('status', $statusValue);
}

$criteria = Criteria::create()->orWhere(
    Criteria::expr()->orX(
        ...$statusExpressions
    ),
);

/** @var Collection<int, Task> $openTasks */
$openTasks = $tasks->matching($criteria);

return $openTasks;
```

for some reason I get:

WHERE status = 'not_started' AND status = 'in_progress'

instead:

WHERE (status = 'not_started' OR status = 'in_progress')